# ClaimsAuthorize relation between action and resource

Tags: .net, claims-based-identity, claims

with the `ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute` (**.net4.5**) I can define required resources and actions like this:

```
[ClaimsAuthorize("View", "Administration")]
```

I can also add multiple attributes for more granular permissions

```
[ClaimsAuthorize("View", "Person")]
[ClaimsAuthorize("Edit", "Settings")]
```

but in the `CheckAccess` Method I have two **seperated** collections, which don't have any relation.

```
  public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
        {
```

So I know there is "View" and "Edit" and on the other side is "Person" and "Settings"

But I don't know whether it was meant

"View Person" or "View Settings" nor

"Edit Person" or "Edit Settings"

How to deal with that?

Am I using the Resource and Action in a way that it was not meant to be?(.net 4.5)

Answer (score 4):

`ClaimsAuthorize` is not part of .NET 4.5 - maybe you mean my version in `IdentityModel` ;)

When you have two attributes on e.g. a method - you will invoke `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` twice. Are you seeing something different?

Then there is a clear relationship between action and resource.

Comment: Yeah your right :) Its part of the identityModel. It integrates so perfectly that I thought it was part of .net :-) 
I didn't check wether the method is triggered twice. I'll do that this evening. Many thanks for your help!

PS Is there somewhere a tutorial of all benefits of the IdentityModel out there? I use  some classes (for example for creating principals) but I feel there is more then I use.